# How to get map from GeoServer using longitude, latitude, zoom level, device width and height?

Tags: geoserver, mobile-gis

I need show a map as image (gif) in my Windows mobile. Only I will get center lat/lon value, zoom level and  width-height mobile screen.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: in what language? with which toolkit? show us the code you've tried so far please

Comment: this is the sample request to get map in image http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=my_map&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fgif&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4030&BBOX=79.957083710937,25.922232,80.599404289063,26.909824&WIDTH=333&HEIGHT=512 but i need like this http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=my_map&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fgif&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4030&lon=79.957083710937&lat=25.922232&WIDTH=333&HEIGHT=512&zoomlevel=5

Comment: seems like you are out of luck then

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Comment: No,I did not got a solution...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up GeoServer to serve out a [WMS](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoserver-intro/overview/wms.html) (Web Map Service) and your client to consume the WMS (which can be as simple as requesting the image via URL).

Comment: ya,But, I have only lat,lon value instead of bounding box. So, i need a request like this http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?
  service=WMS&
  version=1.3.0&
  request=GetMap&
  layers=usa:states&
  srs=EPSG:4326&
  lat=24.956&lon=49.372&zoomlevel=5&
  format=image/png&
  width=780&
  height=330

Comment: I see. Then use your mapping API to calculate the width & height (in lonlat coords) of your screen. In OpenLayers you'd use map.getExtent() and then map.getpixelfromlonlat()

Comment: There is one more problem, I can't use OpenLayers ... :) only , i can use geoserver.